Why do parentheses in CQL WHERE clause return SyntaxException?
SELECT * FROM alarm_history 
  WHERE domain IN ('BAREMETAL','CLOUD','CORE','FIBER','INFRA','PLATFORM','RAN','SECURITY','TRANSPORT') 
  AND ((actual_severity = 'MAJOR') AND (technology = 'LTE')) 
  ALLOW FILTERING;

When I am executing this query on cassandra getting error
SyntaxException: line 1:162 mismatched input 'AND' expecting ')' (... \
  ((actual_severity = 'MAJOR') [AND]...)

but when I am executing by removing the parentheses
SELECT * FROM alarm_history 
  WHERE domain IN ('BAREMETAL','CLOUD','CORE','FIBER','INFRA','PLATFORM','RAN','SECURITY','TRANSPORT')
  AND actual_severity = 'MAJOR' 
  AND technology = 'LTE' 
  ALLOW FILTERING;

it is successfully executed and returning the result
why this is happening..? , logically the query is same and should run both query.
if i am wrong at any point then plz correct me,i am new to cassandra.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

CQL is does not support parentheses in the same way that SQL does.
Sure, in SQL that first statement might be valid. But in CQL, parentheses are only valid in specific instances, like when using the IN operator or calling a function. But simply adding them around items in the WHERE clause will cause the CQL parser to throw the error shown above.

CQL is designed to look like SQL but they are not the same. The CQL grammar only has a subset of SQL's.
CQL is stricter in its implementation such that only the necessary components of a CQL statement are allowed by the CQL parser.
Although the parentheses in this example:
... AND ((actual_severity = 'MAJOR') AND (technology = 'LTE')) ...

logically evaluates to be the same as:
... AND actual_severity = 'MAJOR' AND technology = 'LTE' ...

the parentheses are not required so the CQL parser flags it as invalid syntax leading to the SyntaxException. Cheers!
